# Create hotkey to open a menubar app?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Is it possible to create a hotkey (or other trigger) that opens a menubar app?  I don't mean launch.  I mean, cause the menubar app to display its contents.

Let's say, for example, I wanted to create a hotkey to open a menubar weather app.  Can this be done?

The app I'm trying to open is [open source on Github](https://github.com/danparsons/QuickHue), so I'm open to coding the trigger into the app if need be, but I have no clue how to do that, which means I'd prefer a simpler solution.

I'm using Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickHue"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1
    end tell
end ignoring
```

There is a bug where clicking some status menu items causes scripts to be blocked for about 5 seconds. One workaround is to terminate System Events after the click command:

```
launch application "System Events"
delay 0.2
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item 2 of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The first two lines are needed when System Events is not already running. System Events supports sudden termination, so it should be safe to even send it a KILL signal.

Comment: Thank you SO much.  This was exactly what I needed.  There's a bug in OSX where you can assign hotkeys to menubar app items, but the hotkeys won't work since a menubar app runs in the background.  In other words, you have to click the menubar app to open it before the hotkeys can function.  I consider it a bug anyway!  Your code solved the problem 100%.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I'm trying to do this for CopyClip, but it seems access is denied. Do you know if there is any way around this?