# How to disable long press Caps Lock feature in Mac keyboard?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, imac

There is a feature in Mac keyboard, where keeping the Caps Lock key held for over a second or so, the light will turn on and will change some behavior of input method.

What I want is totally disable this feature, even pressing Caps Lock for a longer duration, the light won't turn on, and don't change other behavior.

I only want to disable "press and hold" feature, my main language isn't English, so I need that feature tap to switch language, but I don't want 'press and hold' feature

How do I do this?

Comment: For those who have never seen this option before in macOS: [it only appears when you add a non-latin input source](https://www.macworld.com/article/3123735/how-to-use-cap-locks-in-macos-sierra-to-switch-between-keyboards-that-use-different-characters.html).

Comment: You might want to combine [Nimesh's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387149/119271) with [Kawa language switcher](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382750/119271) for best results.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I like the Caps Lock keyboard-switching feature, but it conflicts heavily with the old 'press-and-hold for all caps' behavior. It's never 100% reliable. It's baffling that Apple didn't make this either/or, or just allow anyone to disable the Caps Lock press-and-hold function. Has anyone at Apple even tried out this feature? It would take 5 minutes to figure out there's a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences app → Keyboard → Input Sources and uncheck the checkbox against the setting that reads **Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from *language***.

[image]

This should disable the feature and get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: I only want to disable "press and hold" feature, my main language isn't English, so I need that feature tap to switch language, but I don't want 'press and hold' feature

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer to your question.

You can disable the built-in behaviour of the Caps Lock key so that the light won't turn on, and it won't make your typing all uppercase, no matter whether you tap it or hold it down. After making this change the Caps Lock key will do nothing at all, and that means it won't switch input sources either.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open the Keyboard Preferences
3. Press the button for "Modifier Keys..."
4. Select Keyboard "Apple Internal Keyboard"
5. Change "Caps Lock (⇪) Key" to "No Action".

[image: screenshot of keyboard preferences in modifier keys]

I understand this isn't quite you want -- you want Caps Lock to be used only for switching languages, never for uppercase text. Maybe it's possible to combine this with some other tool that installs a custom behaviour for the Caps Lock key.

Answer (score 1):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) comes to save our lives!

After following the [installation instruction](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/) of Karabiner-Elements, open the app, click `Complex Modifications` in the side bar. Here you can add your own rules to modify the default behavior of all keys.

[image]

To achieve what you expect, click `Add your own rule`, copy the following rule to the text field, and click `Save`.

```json
{
    "description": "Caps Lock: press -> Caps Lock; long press -> no effect",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "caps_lock"
            },
            "to_if_alone": [
                {
                    "key_code": "caps_lock"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

All done. Now you have the effect of: "Caps Lock: press -> Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from [last used Latin input source] (check [Change Input Sources settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mchl84525d76/mac) for details); long press -> no effect".