# Change input source with single key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, input-source

I'm not using a Caps Lock key at all, so I've come up with the idea to use it as a way to change the input source.
Problem: keyboard settings want me to hit two keys for a shortcut to register.
Question: is there a way to use only one key?

Comment: Apple already provides a setting to use caps lock to switch between Latin and non Latin keyboards.  What are yours?

Comment: @TomGewecke posted (before me) the same thing I was typing myself, but I wanted to add that there's another solution for [faster language switching](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382747/119271)

Comment: @TomGewecke English (ABC - Extended) and Russian (PC)

Comment: @TomGewecke haven't seen this option, thank you so much!