# TextInputSwitcher gets killed frequently

Tags: keyboard, launchd, plist, input-source

I have been using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to switch input methods recently.

Sometimes, I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> *twice* to trigger the switch.

I found that this process: `TextInputSwitcher` is responsible for the switching.

If it gets killed, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> only restarts this process, so it needs to be pressed again to switch IME.

It's clear that something is killing this process routinely, because the PID of this process is much higher than `TextInputMenuAgent` -- something I think is its neighbor-process.

How can I find out how and why this processed is being killed?

Update:

I've identified the problem.

In `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.TextInputSwitcher.plist`, there's a line of setting: `<key>EnablePressuredExit</key>`.

Which means when mac is running out of memory, `TextInputSwitcher` will be killed automatically.

And if you check `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.TextInputMenuAgent.plist`, there's a `<key>KeepAlive</key>` in it. I guess that's why `TextInputMenuAgent` will never get killed.

Since MacOS is sealed, it seems that no one except Apple can change this setting :(

Comment: Switching between input sources is an absolute wreckage in both macos and windows. Clearly this functional written by people who don't use it.

Comment: Try [Kawa language switcher](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382750/119271) instead.  As for your issue, you also have to look at memory allocation in Activity Monitor, because if you aren't seeing high memory preasure, that setting should have no effect.