# macOs sometimes skips the first press for the keyboard layout change

Tags: keyboard, input-source

MacBook Pro 14" 2021 M1: macOS Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)

I try default <kbd>control ^</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and custom <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Using only one additional source + English.

I noticed that sometimes I can't switch the layout. The problem appears only on the first press after working for a long time in one of the layouts. Karabiner-EventViewer catches this press for control and command + space cases when system skip switch of inputs.

Fixed only using settings "**Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from ABC**".

I have MacBook Pro 13" 2019 Intel i5: macOS Ventura 13.4.1 with same settings and I didn't notice the same problems with him. It's hard to catch, but this problem has become quite uncomfortable in four months of using MacBook Pro 14".

[image: Input Sources]

Comment: Try the other ways to do this -- Caps Lock and Fn/Globe -- and let us know if they are more reliable.

Comment: Try control space .  That is the standard now for macos

Comment: @TomGewecke i need command ⌘ + Space

Comment: @TomGewecke control+space have same troubles: sometime first press not work. BTW Karabiner-EventViewer catches this press as normal, but the OS does not work it out..

Comment: You might have some luck with [Kawa](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382750/119271) to switch languages.

Comment: I have the same problem on a m1 16'' macbook pro. Same problem regardless if I'm using control-space or Fn/Globe.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem..
When I use "Select the previous input source" for my main hotkey they macOs show popup menu with input sources like:

[image: macOs keyboard layout switch menu]

This case does not work correctly and sometimes does not switch the keyboard from the first press.

Looks like bug, "Select next source in input menu" do not show menu (As for me, it should be the opposite). But in any case i recommend to use "Select next source in input menu" for main hotkey, it's work better without lags.

[image: macOs input sources settings]

Tested on macOS Ventura.