# How to prevent Capslock from switching the keyboard language in a certain app?

Tags: macos, language, sonoma, caps-lock

CapsLock is set to switch language in my MacOS.
I don't use any language but English in an IDE for coding.

Is there a solution to disable it for a certain app?

P.S. I was trying it with Karabiner-Elements but couldn't make so far.

Comment: is the cpaslock keyboard shortcut system wide

Comment: What does "switch language" mean? Change input source?

Comment: You could just disable the caps lock shortcut and use one of the other standard shortcuts for switching keyboards:  Control Space or Globe/Fn

Comment: @TomGewecke, yes, but it's not "for a certain app", right?..

Comment: There’s an app (free) called [Kawa](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382750/119271) that could solve this for you

Comment: @Allan, thanks for this reference. Never heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works in Karabiner-Elements (I just did wrong config before).

This configuration shall go to [Complex Modifications](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/typical-complex-modifications-examples/):

```json
{
    "description": "No CapsLock for JetBrains apps",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "com.jetbrains.*"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "caps_lock"
            },
            "to": [],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my case I disabled system CapsLock for all apps which has ID `com.jetbrains.*`.

You may use a terminal command `osascript -e 'id of app "PyCharm"'` to find ID of your app.